# Erase loaded image part by part in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to erase image loaded on canvas  on mouse move and display the background image in wp7.

in C# MakeTransparent method is available.
But in windows phone no such method is available.

what to do ?

Comment: Sorry, but not getting your question correctly. Do you need to erase the image on finger move?

Comment: yes.i want to erase image only where the finger moves

Answer (score 0):

```
Canvas.Opacity = 0; //This will make the control transparent
```

Also you can use .Opacity function almost every visual user control (Image, Grid, Lists etc.)

Comment: using this method the image control will disappear. I want to disappear image part on which mouse or finger moves

Comment: Oh ok sorry, I got your question wrong. Maybe you can cut image part by part programmatically and bind them to Image objects. (I know its not the best way:))

Answer (score 0):

Cleverly, you can use canvas_MouseMove event for an eraser effect.

Just subscribe to canvas mousemove event like in  see the example below

//Canvas MouseMove Event

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.canvas);
            //Initialize line according to currentpoint position.
            Line line = new Line() { X1 = currentPoint.X, Y1 = currentPoint.Y, X2 = oldPoint.X, Y2 = oldPoint.Y };

                line.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Round;
                line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
                line.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
                line.StrokeThickness = 10;
                line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) ;
            ////////////////////////////////
            //Set color & thickness of line. 

            //Line add in canvas children to draw image & assign oldpoint.
            this.canvas.Children.Add(line);
            oldPoint = currentPoint;
        }
```

Not too sure with it but still, I hope it helps.

Comment: i tried ur code.this code gives erasing effect if the background is white because we are putting white lines on the image but in my app the background is also an image.but this code will work if I could make the image transparent at the points where the line is drawn.can I make the image transparent at particular points?how can I do this?

Comment: I am using that for wp8.1 silverlight. Can I remove a point or portion from a line, not full line. Also I have a background image of canvas.